# Hide Fixed Menu while scrolling in both directions

Tags: jquery, wordpress, show-hide

I have a navbar menu that is in a fixed position. While the user is scrolling UP or DOWN I need the navbar is be gone.

I only want the navbar to appear if the person is back to the top position.

Please be gentle: I am not versed in jQuery and the only thing I have achieved is hiding the navbar when scrolling down.

Appreciate the assistance so I can learn!!!

```js
jQuery(function($){
   
var topPosition = 0;
 
 
$(window).scroll(function() {
 
    var scrollMovement = $(window).scrollTop();
   
    if (topPosition < 20 ){
    }
    else{
    if(scrollMovement > topPosition) {
        $('#global-header-section').hide (20);
    } else {
        $('#global-header-section').show (20);
    }
    }
    topPosition = scrollMovement;
});  
   
});
```

Comment: post your html code also.

Answer (score 0):

You are allmost there. Something like this would work:

```
var topPosition = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
 
    var scrollMovement = $(window).scrollTop();
    var nav = $('#global-header-section');
    if (scrollMovement == topPosition){      
         nav.show (20);
    }
    else{
        if(!nav.is(':hidden')){         
            nav.hide (20);
        }
        
    }
    
});
```

Se working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z27xk9bg/2/